# Get current user's access token without user picker dialog

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, google-api, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication with the web API in conjunction with the Google APIs to access the user's Google Drive, so I need the Firebase user's access token (via the `GoogleAuthProvider`) to hand it over to the Google API.  I do this by taking it out of the result of `signInWithPopup`:

```
const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
const { credential } = result;
if (credential === null) return undefined;
if (!hasOwnProperty(credential, "accessToken")) return undefined;
const accessToken = checkString(credential.accessToken);
```

This works fine, but it has the unfortunate side effect that in case the user is already logged in, it will still display the popup and let the user choose whether they want to use their current account or pick a different one.  I'd like to just get the access token without requiring them to go through that picker.

I tried

```
const result = user.reauthenticateWithPopup(provider);
```

where `user` is the current Firebase user, but that still displays the picker popup.

Another approach was this:

```
const cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(await user.getIdToken());
const result = await user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred);
```

This one weirdly fails with a 400 and the message:

```
Invalid id_token in IdP response: eyJhbGci...
```

Is there any other way I'm missing to get an access token?

Comment: Are you trying to refresh the OAuth access token without opening the OAuth popup?

Comment: No, I don't have the access token because I don't save it between sessions.

Comment: Well you have to save it, because Firebase Auth does not save it for you. You are confusing Firebase ID token obtained via `user.getIdToken()` with the OAuth access token. That is why you are getting this error.